# Can a desktop app write to command line using javascript?

Tags: javascript, command-line, desktop-application

Say I use NW.js to get a native html/css/javascript app working. How would I use javascript to edit the folder contents of directories on the user system when they drag and drop in a folder, to read and write in files?

And then write to command line to command it to do something?

Comment: You'll need to leverage Node.js, which should already be baked into NW.js (Node-Webkit.js)

Comment: @ndugger Hey, thanks for writing. How would Node.js go about it? It's a completely offline app so I'm wondering if that might be a problem.

Comment: Node has a filesystem API that you can use to read/write files. Check out the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/fs.html) for more details.